# Redireccionar de http a https excepto una pagina

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

Estoy redireccionando de http a https a mi pagina desde el htaccess (estoy usando laravel), pero necesito que una pagina en especifico sea la excepcion a esta regla y siga utilizando http:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^misitio.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

He visto que es algo parecido a esto:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/pagina-sin-https
```

Pero no me ha funcionado, agradezco alguna idea